# Optional Javax Filter with Jersey ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, filter, jersey, servlet-filters, keycloak

I have an existing Project with an Jersey **ContainerRequestFilter** for a REST Service for security checks. Additionally I have to add a Javax **Servlet Filter** from Keycloak with its code should not be changed, for security checks as well. 
These two filters should both be used for a smooth integration, so the request should pass if one of them is valid, or both. Just like an boolean **'OR Conjunction'**

**web.xml** for keycloak filter

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>Keycloak Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Keycloak Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/keycloak/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Existing **ContainerRequestFilter**

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter { ... }
```

With this Configuration the Keycloak filter is triggered first and on failure the SecurityFilter will never be invoked.

How can I link those in an '**OR Conjunction**' **without coding** in the Keycloak Filter and maybe even without coding in the SecurityFilter?

Comment: You would have to implement this yourself - there isn't a standard way to create an interaction like you want.

Comment: I implemented a new Filter which skips or triggers the ServletFilter manually depending on the other Filters success. The outcome of the first filter is now saved as request attribute